# Small or large caps on title?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

It would be extra nice if `UNIX & LINUX` on the title would be `Unix & Linux`. Would be even nicer if the `nix` part of `Unix` was done in small caps (as [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix)):

> ...officially trademarked as UNIX, sometimes also written as Unix with small caps...

Comment: `Uɴɪx & Lɪɴᴜx` … I like the idea of having them both in small caps.

Comment: @gilles That's very tempting, and has an authoritative feel. It also has an advantage of consistency (between the two terms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good suggestion. Expect the header update in the next build.

Comment: This change looks great!

Comment: @Jin But there are _faked_ small caps now. This is ugly and even worse than large caps only.